# .Net HttpHandler not working in android device

Tags: c#, android, asp.net

I have created ASP.Net httphandler to count number of visits for MP3 files. Httphandler is being used in web application as well as in ios + android application.

It is working fine in web + ios application. If I run android application in Samsung Galaxy S then it is playing MP3 files perfectly but it is not working in Samsung Galaxy Ace mobile.

I do not know what is wrong in my asp.net code. Below is code of httphandler.

```
public class MP3DownloadHanlder : IHttpHandler , IRequiresSessionState
  {

      public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
      {
              //Here I increment number of visit by filename in request
              string filename = context.Request.QueryString["Title"] + ".mp3";
              string path = context.Server.MapPath("audio");
              string file = path + "\\" + filename;
              if (System.IO.File.Exists(file))
              {
                  FileStream fs = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
                  context.Response.Buffer = true;
                  context.Response.Clear();
                  context.Response.ClearContent();
                  context.Response.ClearHeaders();
                  context.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename);
                  context.Response.AddHeader("content-length", fs.Length.ToString());
                  context.Response.ContentType = "audio/mpeg";
                  byte[] bytes = new byte[fs.Length];
                  int bytesToRead = (int)fs.Length;
                  int bytesRead = 0;
                  while (bytesToRead > 0)
                  {
                      int n = fs.Read(bytes, bytesRead, bytesToRead);
                      if (n == 0) break;
                      bytesRead += n;
                      bytesToRead -= n;
                  }
                  bytesToRead = bytes.Length;
                  context.Response.OutputStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
              }

          context.Response.End();
      }

      public bool IsReusable
      {
          get
          {
              return false;
          }
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no **Content-Disposition** of `attachement`. It should be [`attachment`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec19.html#sec19.5.1).

Comment: Sorry it was my spell mistake. I just corrected it. But still no luck

Comment: What's a sample filename it fails for?

Answer (score 0):

Try the mime types "audio/mpeg3" and "audio/x-mpeg-3" for your ContentType.

And also "audio/mp3" and "audio/x-mp3". I think you have used the correct one, but it may have been poorly implemented on the device.

Comment: Finally I get it working by changing content-disposition header in response.

 context.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "inline; filename=" + filename);

I only need to change attachment to inline and it is working in all android devices now.

Thank you all for your help